# ¿Como agregar cadenas correctamente a un bucle For en Java Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, bucle-for

Tengo un problema al recorrer el bucle for en mi programa. De hecho no sé si en base al enunciado esté haciendo correctamente el programa(si alguien tiene otra lógica podría ayudarme). En fin el error es que deseo que me pida los parámetros cliente por cliente pero al agregar 4 clientes al arreglo no me pide facilitar los datos del primer cliente sino que se pasa al segundo. Adjunto el enunciado y el ejercicio hecho hasta ahora. Agradezco de antemano si alguien me ayuda con la lógica y a resolver mi problema :(

```
/*
“El náufrago satisfecho” ofrece hamburguesas sencillas (S), dobles (D) y 
triples (T),
las cuales tienen un costo de $2.0, $3.5 y $4.8 respectivamente. 
La empresa acepta tarjetas de crédito con un cargo de 5 % sobre la compra. 
Lea datos de los N clientes, el tipo de hamburguesa y cantidad, 
la forma de pago (contado, tarjeta_crédito). 
Cada cliente adquiere una hamburguesa, las cuales pueden ser de diferente 
tipo, 
realice un programa para determinar cuánto deben pagar cada uno, si hay N 
clientes. 
También calcule cuantos clientes compraron hamburguesas: sencillas, dobles y 
triples.
Finalmente, presente el valor recaudado por la venta de las hamburguesas a 
los N clientes.
*/
package hamburguesa;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hamburguesa {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int longitud=0;
    double sencilla=2.0, doble=3.5, triple=4.8;
    Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("¿Cuantos clientes desean comprar hamburguesa?: ");
    longitud=entrada.nextInt();
    String clientes[]=new String[longitud];

    for(int i=0; i<clientes.length; i++){
        System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del cliente "+(i+1)+":");
        clientes[i]=entrada.nextLine();
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Dentro del for, en vez de usar nextLine() proba con next().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

en este apartado

```
for(int i=0; i<clientes.length; i++){
        System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del cliente "+(i+1)+":");
        clientes[i]=entrada.nextLine();
    }
```

cambia

```
clientes[i]=entrada.nextLine();
```

por

```
clientes[i]=entrada.next();
```

Comment: Si funciono bro

Comment: Muy bien, que bueno, que tengas un excelente día